# Disabling pop-up of secure and non-secure content in Internet Explorer

Tags: security, internet-explorer, popup

I have few images on a web page which are fetched from HTTP server while whole web page is on HTTPS. So in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 I get this pop up:

> This page contains both secure and non-secure items

Majority of users use Internet Explorer. Somehow they are getting worried about this pop-up. Even though I told some of the users about settings in IE, I dread telling everyone.

Does anyone know how I can disable this pop-up through JavaScript or any other way where the control will be in my hands?

Comment: Can encrypting the images path solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot disable it. It is a security feature of the browser. It prevents possible cross site scripting XSS for secure sites.

Your best bet is to host all images, css, javascripts, etc from the secure server also.

Answer (score 5):

You can't disable the popups.  If you could, that's what the bad guys would do, and then there'd be no point to the security popup.

Move your images to your secure server, and the popups will go away because there's nothing being served unsecurly on a secure page.

Answer (score -1):

Go to internet explorer-tools-security tab-custom level-scripting-active scripting-disable.

This should solve the problem